# make string variable to PHP source

Tags: php

i have some variable that have some source. like this:

```
$sc = "$aa=4;";
```

i want to make the string- **"$aa=4;"** to a PHP sorce that i can use, like this:

```
echo $aa;
```

there is any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just write `$aa = 4;` in the first place?

Comment: Where is this variable coming from?  User input?  Database?  File system?  Chances are, there's a better way to do this.  Saving code as a string is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It's complicated to explain. I have no other way to do what I want to do.

Comment: Bad.Design. Unless you want to write something like phpFiddle, but it already exists.

Comment: @user3419680: I'm betting you *do* have a better way, but unless you wanna write your own PHP syntax parser, you're probably gonna have to resort to `eval()`.  Just remember that if you are allowing user input in there, you need to validate it first.  Always assume everything from the user is malicious.

Comment: @moonwave99 Believe me I would rather avoid that, at the moment I do not see a way to avoid itץ

Comment: [99% this is a XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so please tell us about your goal, better than about your attempted solution : ))

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't but you can (God forgive me) use `eval`;

```
$sc = "$aa=4;";
eval($sc);
echo $aa;
```

Be aware that if your `$sc` is user provided variable, your server will probably blow up.

And yes, this is probably [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)